# How Do I Check If Div Is On Screen Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been working on this for a while, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to get my image page to load properly...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="lytebox.js?version=10-25-2020-2-12" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lytebox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<style type="text/css">
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
#xoverlay{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 90;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
-moz-opacity: 0.6;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#xloading {
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
left: 0%;
height: 25%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font: 150% 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<img src="graphics/morebtn_photospagedarker.jpg" style="display: none">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearOverlayOnLoad() {
    var id = "xoverlay";
    if (document.getElementById)
      var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    else if (document.all)
      var obj = document.all[id];
    else if (document.layers)
      var obj = document.layers[id];
    obj.style.display = 'none';

//CALL MOST RECENT PAGE HERE!!
 page7("true");

 document.getElementById("more").innerHTML="<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='nextpage();'><img onmouseout='this.src=\"graphics/morebtn_photospage.jpg\"'' onmouseover='this.src=\"graphics/morebtn_photospagedarker.jpg\"' width='60' height='60' src='graphics/morebtn_photospage.jpg' style='border-radius: 100px'></a>"; // Create More Button
 resizephotopage();
}
    
  </script>

  
  </head>



<script type="text/javascript">
maxgalleries=100
evenrow=0;
r=0; e=0; buildcode=""; // Call Variables

function makeholders(){
for (l=0;l<=maxgalleries;l++)
   {
    document.write('<div id="'+l+'holder"></div>');
    document.write('<div id="'+l+'hidden"></div>');
   }
}


    function insertalbum(location, title, totalpics, tf){ // Create Insert Function Used In "photos_list.htm"
if (tf=="true"){
if(r>=maxgalleries){document.getElementById("more").innerHTML="";return} // If MaxGalleries Do Not Show More Button
    if (evenrow==0){buildcode='<table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align:top;" width="100%"><tr><td width="320px" align="left" style="vertical-align:top"><a id="CurrentAEvent' + location +'" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('+String.fromCharCode(39)+''+location+'-01'+String.fromCharCode(39)+').click()" ><img id="CurrentImgEvent' + location +'"  src="albums/'+location+'/01.jpg" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #D3D3D3; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 6px solid #800000;" width="320" height="213" align="left"></a><p align="left"><br></td><td width="80%" align="left" style="vertical-align:center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('+String.fromCharCode(39)+''+location+'-01'+String.fromCharCode(39)+').click()">'+title+'<br>('+totalpics+' Photos)</a><p>'} // Create Slideshow Type 1
if (evenrow==1){buildcode='<table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%"><tr><td width="20%" align="right"><td width="80%" align="right" style="vertical-align:center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('+String.fromCharCode(39)+''+location+'-01'+String.fromCharCode(39)+').click()">'+title+'<br>('+totalpics+' Photos)</a></td><td width="320px" align="right"><a id="CurrentAEvent' + location +'" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="document.getElementById('+String.fromCharCode(39)+''+location+'-01'+String.fromCharCode(39)+').click()" ><img id="CurrentImgEvent' + location +'"  src="albums/'+location+'/01.jpg" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #D3D3D3; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 6px solid #800000;" width="320" height="213" align="right"></a><p align="right"><br><p>'} // Create Slideshow Type 2
buildcode=buildcode+'';
if (evenrow==0){buildcode=buildcode+'<td width="20%" align="center"></td></tr></table>';} // Separate Tables If They Are Even (gives this a nicer effect)
if (evenrow==1){buildcode=buildcode+'</tr></table>'; evenrow=-1;}
document.getElementById(r+'holder').innerHTML=buildcode;
document.getElementById('CurrentAEvent' + location +'').onmouseover = function(){document.getElementById('CurrentImgEvent' + location +'').style = "box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #D3D3D3; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 6px solid #616161;"}
document.getElementById('CurrentAEvent' + location +'').onmouseout = function(){document.getElementById('CurrentImgEvent' + location +'').style = "box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #D3D3D3; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 6px solid #800000;"}
evenrow++; r++; buildcode=""
}
else{
if(e>=maxgalleries){return}
for (i=1;i<=totalpics;i++)
{
    if (i<=9){  
        buildcode=buildcode+'<a href="albums/'+location+'/0'+i+'.jpg" class="lytebox" data-lyte-options="group:'+location+'" data-title="'+title+'" id="'+location+'-0'+i+'"></a>';} // Create The Link To Click
        else {
        buildcode=buildcode+'<a href="albums/'+location+'/'+i+'.jpg" class="lytebox" data-lyte-options="group:'+location+'" data-title="'+title+'"></a>';} // Create The Link To Click If Slide Count Is Less Than 10
}
e++
}
}

function nextpage() {
// SET UP CALL FOR ALL SUCCEEDING PAGES HERE!
if (last==7){
   page6("true");
   last--;
   resizephotopage();
   return}

if (last==6){
   page5("true");
   last--;
   resizephotopage();
   return}

if (last==5){
   page4("true");
   last--;
   resizephotopage();
   return}

if (last==4){
   page3("true");
   last--;
   resizephotopage();
   return}

if (last==3){
   page2("true");
   last--;
   resizephotopage();
   return}

   if (last==2){
   page1("true");
   last--;
   document.getElementById("more").innerHTML=""; // If This Is The Last Page Do Not Show The More Button
   resizephotopage();
   return}
   
   
}


function resizephotopage(){ // Resizes Div To Fit Perfectly Into IFRAME
newheight=document.getElementById('thispage').scrollHeight+50;
      if (newheight < 860){newheight=860;}
      window.parent.document.getElementById('photoshere').height=newheight+'px';      
      }

</script>

<body style="background-color:FFFFFF" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">

<body onload="clearOverlayOnLoad();">
<div id="xoverlay">
  <div id="xloading">
    Loading, please wait...<br>
    <img src="/graphics/xloading.gif" alt="Loading" width=126 height=22>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="thispage">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p align="left"><font size="5" color="#800000" face="Verdana"><b>Click On An Album To See The 
Pictures:</font></b></p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center">




<script type="text/javascript">
makeholders(); 


<?php
$sub_req_url = 'https://www.mywebsite.us/photos_list.htm';
$ch = curl_init($sub_req_url);
$encoded = '';
// include GET as well as POST variables; your needs may vary.
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
  $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
// chop off last ampersand
$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>


//INCLUDE ALL PAGES HERE (Marked "false") TO CREATE HOLDERS
last=7;
page7("false");
page6("false");
page5("false");
page4("false");
page3("false");
page2("false");
page1("false");

</script>
</div>
<div id="more" align="center"></div> <!-- Create More Button To Modify -->
<script>document.getElementById(e+'hidden').innerHTML=buildcode;</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is all the coding I have that needs accounted for...
I need to have a function that checks when the more button is on screen, however this is a bit tricky considering this is inside an iframe. I am not sure if it is physically possible to do this, but if you could at all help me I would be very appreciative.

Comment: hi.show your html and css code

Comment: Is the content in the iframe hosted on the same server as your main web application or is it a third-party server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I been looking at my code and I think there is no way to solve my issue. I think in the future I might redo my code, however for now I will leave it the way it is. Thank you to all who spent time looking at or into my issue.